# DisplayActionSheet() return type

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I simply want to set

```
Label.Text = DisplayActionSheet(<ActionSheetArguments>);
```

but I keep getting an error that System.Threading.Tasks.Task cannot be converted to string. The box that pops up when I am typing DisplayActionSheet() says

```
Usage:
String x = DisplayActionSheet()
```

so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Note: The action sheet pops up how I intend it to, it just returns the wrong data type.

EDIT: I currently have the line

```
var result = DisplayActionSheet(<args>)
```

I just don't know what I can do with result from here? It's of the type Task obviously, I just don't know what to do with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DisplayActionSheet](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups/#Guiding_Users_Through_Tasks)() is an async method, so you need to use `await`

```
var action = await DisplayActionSheet ("ActionSheet: SavePhoto?", "Cancel", "Delete", "Photo Roll", "Email");
```